# I need to generate a modal popup dynamically that contains a user control when a button/link is clicked

Tags: javascript, c#, html, bootstrap-4

I have an asp.net web forms website that I am trying to enhance by adding popup modals that show the rental rates for equipment available to rent.  On most pages, the rates are 'static' and are posted at the top of the page for all the equipment on that page.  However on a few pages, the rates cannot be ‘static’ at the top because each piece of equipment has different rates, thus the need for the popup.

I have created a user control (I'll call 'Rate Card') that does the database lookups and rate calculations for the equipmentID passed to it, and it then creates a formatted DIV (complete with stylings, disclaimers, and links to the Terms and Conditions).  For the 'static' pages, I simply insert this DIV in my document’s asp:placeholder and I'm done.  For the other pages, I would like to keep using my Rate Card user control as the contents of the popup.

Here is what I have tried:

- asp:buttons using the 'onClick' to initiate server side code to generate the Rate Card.  It is then inserted into a block of bootstrap modal code in the document, and finally the server side calls some javascript code (via ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript) that displays the modal popup.  This works, however the webpage reloads each time you click on the View Rates button, and scrolls back to the top.  If I try to check for 'isPostBack' and just return if it is, the page still reloads and all I have is the header and footer from my site master.
- I started coding to put the bootstrap modal block inside an asp:UpdatePanel, but after reading several different posts, it seems the page would still reload.

So what I am wanting to accomplish is to have the user click an element beside the name of a piece of equipment (button, link, label, div, etc.) and have the something trigger the Rate Card to be generated, and then display as a modal popup.

My programming background is C# mainly for WinForms client applications, but have some experience with asp.net websites.  So, I may need some extra guidance and examples.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

**ADDED CODE:**

Button source:

```
<asp:Button ID="ShowRates" runat="server" OnClick="ShowRates_Click" CommandArgument="0" Text="View Rates"  ></asp:Button>
```

Button code behind:

```
protected void ShowRates_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ID = ((Button)sender).CommandArgument;
    if (int.TryParse(ID, out int assetID) == false) return;

    assetCard_ShowRate(sender, e, assetID);
}

private void assetCard_ShowRate(object sender, EventArgs e, int assetID)
{
    Controllers.AssetController ctlr = new Controllers.AssetController();
    var rates = ctlr.GetAssetRateCardsByAssetID(assetID);

    UserControls.RatesTable2 ratesTable = (UserControls.RatesTable2)LoadControl("~/UserControls/RatesTable2.ascx");
    ratesTable.BuildRateCard(rates, "");

    //Add the rate card control to the placeholder
    phRateCard.Controls.Add(ratesTable);

    //Call the javascrip function to show the popup
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Popup", "ShowPopup();", true);
}
```

Page code behind:  Bootstrap popup class block:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal-label">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phRateCard" runat="server">
                    <%--Place Rate Card Here--%>
                </asp:PlaceHolder>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowPopup() {
        $("#myModal").modal("show");
    }
</script>
```

It seems that the page reload is occurring right after the javascript is called, and before the javascript starts to run.

Comment: If clicking a button also reloads the page, you need to call `preventDefault()` on the click event. Please put relevant code in your question.

Comment: Thanks Chris, but I'm not sure where to place the preventDefault() call.  It doesn't seem to be part of C#.  I've added my code as requested.

Comment: Here's the basic idea: https://jsfiddle.net/wqxhgnbk/ however I have no idea how this is supposed to be handled in your case. What you can do to prevent the automatic form submission is to add `type="button"` to the button.

Comment: Thanks again Chris.  I understood where you were going with this, but I didn't know exactly how to do it either.  I'll post what I had to do to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I was able to accomplish what I needed using the following code:

Button source:

```
<button id="ShowRates2" runat="server" type="button" class="btn btn-link treUnderline" style="color:black" onclick="ShowRates_Click(this)">View Rates</button>
```

Button code behind:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string ShowRates(string AssetID)
{
    int assetID = int.Parse(AssetID);

    ListLayoutByCategory5 method = new ListLayoutByCategory5();
    string html = method.BuildRateCard(assetID);
    return html;
}

private string BuildRateCard(int assetID)
{
    Controllers.AssetController ctlr = new Controllers.AssetController();
    var rates = ctlr.GetAssetRateCardsByAssetID(assetID);

    UserControl uc = new UserControl();
    UserControls.RatesTable2 ratesTable = (UserControls.RatesTable2)uc.LoadControl("~/UserControls/RatesTable2.ascx");
    ratesTable.BuildRateCard(rates, "", false);

    //Get the HTML code of the ratesTable control (uses RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter(StringWriter(StringBuilder))) )
    string html = ratesTable.HTML;
    return html;
}
```

Page source:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal-label">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            </div>
            <div id="popupBody" class="modal-body">
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phRateCard" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
    function ShowRates_Click(asset) {
        var selectedAssetID = asset.getAttribute("assetid");
        PageMethods.ShowRates(selectedAssetID, ShowRatesPopup);
    }

    function ShowRatesPopup(popupHTML) {
        document.getElementById('popupBody').innerHTML = popupHTML;
        $("#myModal").modal("show");
    }

</script>
```

This is basically what I had to do.  On the button’s ‘onclick’ event, I called the JavaScript function ‘ShowRates(this)’.  This function extracted the assetid from the attributes, and then called the server-side method ‘ShowRates’ passing the assetid to it.  This method created the rate card user control and return a string containing the raw html code of that user control.  (This used C#’s  control.RenderControl method to get the html.)

Once the JavaScript function received the html code from the server, it then called JavaScript function ‘ShowRatesPopup’ and passed the html code to it.  This function inserted the html code into the ‘popupBody’ and then called the modal popup ‘#myModal’.